# Does not create log4net file if its referenced from another project C# application logging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have created a separate project which will maintain all datataccess, models and logging. I'm using log4net as logging tool. It works fine only if the Logger class file is within the project itself.

1. I have windows form application "ClearningApp.UI" which contains mainly the application UI and class Library project "CLearningApp.Library" which contains DataAccess, Configuration, DatabaseSetup other utilities of the application.
2. I have to start logging everything from my application from UI to everything in library so I created a folder called Logging inside CLeaningApp.Library and created a class Logger

```html
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace LearningAppLibrary.Log
{
    public class Logger
    {
        public static log4net.ILog GetLogger([CallerFilePath]string filename = "")
        {
            return log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(filename);
        }

        public static readonly log4net.ILog log = GetLogger();
    }
}
```

3. In the windows form application project "ClearningApp.UI", on app.config I have added the below log4net code

```html
<configSections>
   <section name="Database" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
   <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler"/>
</configSections>
  
  <Database>
    <add key="ClearningDB" value="Server=DESKTOP-AA\SQLDATA;Database=CLearningDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
  </Database>

  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %C{1}.%M: %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Clearning.exe.log"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="1000MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %C{1}.%M: %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>


</configuration>
```

4. I have added assembly code in the AssemblyInfo.cs of CLearningApp.UI

```html
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

5. In the program.cs file I have the below code

```html
namespace CLearning
{
    static class Program
    {
        
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
 
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            bool isServiceRunning = ConnectionStatusCheckerService.CheckSQLServiceStatus();
            if(!isServiceRunning)
            {
                Logger.log.Error("SQL is not running");
            }
            else
            {
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
            Logger.log.Info("SQL is running, application started");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added project reference ClearningLibrary to ClearningApp.UI but the log file does not get created. I do not get any error on debug and the application starts but no log file nor the log.

Please guide my mistake.

Regards,
Arp

Comment: Are logs printed in Console ( through ConsoleAppender )?

Comment: I think https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#first-log applies.

Comment: It will be logged in a file as RollingFileAppender